# Che dicono i miei headphones bluetooth?

Tags: translation

Quando uso i miei headphones (Bose QC35 ii), una voce dice qualcosa. Prima dice "batteria al cento per cento". Poi dice qualcosa che non capisco. Sembra "connesu lei a <> in corso". Credo significhi "connection to <> in progress", ma le parole non sono chiare per me. Che dicono i miei headphones bluetooth?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Comment: Side comment: next time first try to get the meaning looking for the term [connection on a dictionary](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Inglese/C/connection.shtml) since this kind of question might be considered off topic.

Comment: @abarisone Thank you! I had looked up the word, but I really thought I could hear "L" and "ei" rather than "n" and "e" sounds (why I thought "lei" rather than "<connessio>ne"). The "io" part also sounds a lot like "u" to me. But if there is nothing feasible that sounds like "conne su lei a...", I assume you are right, and I am mishearing it (or it's not a good voice)!

Comment: Would it be possible that what the voice is saying is not Italian? Or that it is an incorrect Italian translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le tue cuffie (headphones) dicono:

> Connessione a <> in corso (connection to <> in progress)

Comment: Ha senso... La voce non è chiara... Ho sentito "l" invece "n"!